# What a place that sells rocks is called

Tags: rocks, open-data

If a nursery sells plants, I'm wondering what a place that sells rocks is called. Something where they offer rocks of various sizes like [this](https://www.classicrockinc.com/our-products/gravel-river-rock):

[image]

Well, those are all river rocks, but I'm wondering about for any rocks, even boulders or "slices" (or perhaps "slates"). In bulk/wholesale and retail. Perhaps a standard reference/source that has them would be nice but not necessary.

I am interested to know how rocks are harvested, what the process and distribution is and such.

Comment: Try looking in you local "Yellow Pages", business telephone directory under *Soil and Gravel Supplies*

Comment: I can understand the opting to close, since it's indeed not really closely tied to any of the scientific subjects.  That said, it's tough, because there's really no great place to ask such a question, and it seems a relatively worthwhile one... glad for Fred's comment, and hopeful others may add more information :)